# PHP MYSQL, How to compare same date two timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Using **PHP time()** function, I have got this timestamp - 1407760251  (11-08-2014)

Also using only **YY-MM-DD (date picker)** I have generated this timestamp - 1407708000 (11-08-2014)

MySQL table has time() timestamp, I want to filter same day records from MYSQL table how to do it? please help me.. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: is the timestamp a string or datetime field?

Comment: @sri no timestamp store as int

Answer (score 1):

Use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the PHP side:

```
date("d-m-Y", $millis);
```

and use [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) on the MySQL side to make a timestamp comparable to the date you have:

```
SELECT someFields
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATE(myDate) = date("d-m-Y", $millis)
```